# Return Try or Future As Generic Container

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Instead of using overloaded methods in `object JSONSourceLoaderUtil`, I want to switch to pattern matching style. How do I handle the resultant `Try[JValue]` and `Future[JValue]` as `F[JValue]`?

Imports and case classes,

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import org.json4s.JsonAST.{JObject, JValue}

trait DataSource
case class LocalFile(input: File) extends DataSource
case class RemoteResource(url: String, req: JValue) extends DataSource
```

What I have now,

```
object JSONSourceLoaderUtil {

  def jsonFrom[F[_], S <: DataSource](source: S)(f: S => F[JValue])(implicit ev: Monad[F]): F[JValue] = ev.bind(ev.point(source))(f)

  def extractFrom(source: RemoteResource): Future[JValue] = {
    Future( ... ).flatMap(input => Future.fromTry(Parser.parseFromChannel(Channels.newChannel(input))))
}

  def extractFrom(source: LocalFile): Try[JValue] = Parser.parseFromFile(source.input)
}
```

How do I convert to pattern matching style? Is there a another way to do this if I have painted myself into a corner? Thanks.

```
object JSONSourceLoaderUtil {

def jsonFrom[F[_], S <: DataSource](source: S)(f: S => F[JValue])(implicit ev: Monad[F]): F[JValue] = ev.bind(ev.point(source))(f)

def extractFrom(source: DataSource): F[JValue] = source match {
    case RemoteResource(url, request) => Future( ... )
      .flatMap(input => Future.fromTry(Parser.parseFromChannel(Channels.newChannel(input))))) // cannot convert Future to F

    case LocalFile(input) => Parser.parseFromFile(input)  // cannot convert Try to F
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired `F` depends on the type of the data source. So why not make this explicit?

```
trait DataSource[F[_]] {
  def extract: F[JValue]
}

case class LocalFile(input: File) extends DataSource[Try] {
  def extract = Parser.parseFromFile(input)
}

case class RemoteResource(url: String, req: JValue) extends DataSource[Future] {
  def extract = Future( ... )
    .flatMap(input => Future.fromTry(Parser.parseFromChannel(Channels.newChannel(input)))))
}
```

Removing the extract method and writing

```
def extractFrom[F[_]](source: DataSource[F]): F[JValue] = source match {
    case RemoteResource(url, request) => Future( ... )
      .flatMap(input => Future.fromTry(Parser.parseFromChannel(Channels.newChannel(input)))))

    case LocalFile(input) => Parser.parseFromFile(input)
  }
}
```

should also probably work, [at least in Scala 2.12](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9760). But I find the first solution to be cleaner.

Comment: I came across the second solution but it didn't compile. How would I know it was a compiler bug?!? Many Thanks. I have a  follow-up q. Wouldn't the 1st solution "OO" like (I could use the wrong term)? for instance I can't convert this solution to haskell.

Comment: Well, Scala isn't Haskell. And in particular, its support for this specific pattern (GADT) is limited.